# OpenCV for web/ javascript

Tags: javascript, opencv, express, machine-learning, feature-detection

I have to use OpenCV in a web application. I know the Python and the C++ library but I need to use it with Express.js now. For this I need object detection, feature detection, preferably SIFT and eventually basic stuff from the machine learning module.

I looked into opencvjs project: https://github.com/ucisysarch/opencvjs, but I have some concerns with it. Has anyone experience with this one? As far as I understood I need to setup emscripten sdk which compiles the OpenCV library to javascript? I already tried another implementation in JS initially but it was running pretty slowly. Also it seems, as it does not provide extra modules for SURF or SIFT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opencvjs is for the browser as far as I know. You could check out my npm package: https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs, which provides JavaScript bindings to opencv3. Machine learning is not fully implemented yet, but you can use Support Vector Machines. Also it provides HOG, face detection, feature detection and matching. If you compile the library with extra modules you can use SIFT and SURF.

You can use the package for server-side CV tasks, with express, electron or with your app running in a Docker container.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a base image or example for docker?

Comment: I only have some images for different opencv3 versions for CI: https://hub.docker.com/r/justadudewhohacks/. You can pull one of these and pull from some node base image and you should be ready to go.